# wsp Template loaded, but site creation problem

Tags: active-directory, solution-package, site-template, template

I have a wsp file from a different farm sent to me and would like to use it on my organization's sharepoint environment.

I loaded the template and activated it and can see it as a template when I want to create a new site.

The issue is while the site is being created, it pops up the login credential telling me to login to the previous sharepoint farm. After canceling the popup several times, the site gets created with the template but for every link I follow, it pops up the login screen before leading me to it. Please how do I eliminate this several login pop-ups??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have them send you the solution. They coded the the solution to be deployed to the previous farm. That's why you're being prompted.